# How I conditionally propagate <p:dataTable> page event fire

Tags: events, jsf-2, primefaces

In my application I have a `<p:dataTable>` with pagination and LazyDatamodel, and at the bottom of the form I have a `CommandButton`
named `update` by which I can save the edited rows.
Problem is :
1. When from one page user want to leave the page with out saving edited rows then I want to propagate the fired `page` event and stay on the current page
not to leave the page , and if there are no change in the current page at that case user can leave the page.

Code of .xhtml is given below :

```
<h:form id="userListForm">
    <p:panel id="userListPanel" header="#{adbBundle['userList.panel.header']}" toggleable="true">
        <p:dataTable var="user" id="userTable" value="#{userDataModel}" lazy="true" paginator="true" rows="25" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="25,50,100" widgetVar="userDataTable" styleClass="userTable" selectionMode="single" >


            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="resetFiter" styleClass="dataTableResetFilter">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{adbBundle['filter.resetText']}" />
                        <p:spacer width="10" />
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-circle-close" actionListener="#{userListController.resetUserTable}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column id="nameColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['name']}" sortBy="#{user.fullName}" filterBy="#{user.fullName}" styleClass="userName">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.fullName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="statusColumn" headerText="#{adbBundle['status']}" sortBy="#{user.active}" filterBy="#{user.statusText}" filterMatchMode="exact" styleClass="manageStatus"
                filterOptions="#{userListController.statusOptions}" rendered="#{manageUser != null and manageUser != ''}">
                <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="userRadio" value="#{user.statusText}" styleClass="roleRadio">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{adbBundle['active']}" itemValue="Active" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{adbBundle['inactive']}" itemValue="Inactive" />

                        <p:ajax listener="#{userListController.changeStatus}" />
                        <f:attribute name="user" value="#{user}" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

How it can be implemented? Any pointer will be very helpful to me. Thanks..

Comment: What is your functional requirement? If you want to ask for user's confirmation, use JavaScript `return confirm('Are you sure you want to quit?')` in `onclick` attribute of `<h:commandButton>`. If you want to fire a request every time user clicks the button, just return `null` from an action method for a postback to the same view on some condition, and navigation case outcome otherwise. If you shed more light on your problem we'll be able to give more applicable advice.

Comment: @skuntsel: thaks for your reply, I want to stop to leaving the current page without saving the current page's content, but when I click on another page without saving current pages content that another page is being displayed how i stop going to another page ??